# Событие onended в теге <audio> не работает в мобильных браузерах

Tags: javascript, html, аудио

Я хотел сделать мою библиотеку аудиокниг доступной для родителей.
Так, чтобы можно было нажать на планшете кнопку и слушать последовательно 
файлы из определенной директории. Для этого я хотел для всех дирекорий с файлами написать примерно такой html - код:

```
<html>
<body>

01:<audio id="player01" src="001 Track 01.mp3" controls onended="player02.play();"></audio><br><br>

02:<audio id="player02" src="001 Track 02.mp3" controls onended="player03.play();"></audio><br><br>

03:<audio id="player03" src="001 Track 03.mp3" controls></audio><br><br>

</body>
</html>
```

Пример такого кода - по адресу 
http://junecat.ru/bt/AudioBooks/000/slu.htm
На Хроме под windows все отрабатывает отлично - заканчивается один файл, и начинается воспроизведение другого.
Но ни на одном телефоне или планшете этотак не работает - там проигрывается одинн файл, и воспроизведение останавливается.
Нет ли какого то способа вылечить это? пните меня в нужном направлении, пожалуйста.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28701800/815386

в двух словах - приделывайте событие onended в js

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать все делать вручную:

```
var myAudio = new Audio('book.mp3'); 
myAudio.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    ...
    anotherMyAudio.play();
    ...
}, false);
myAudio.play();
```

Но вообще, проблема может скрываться и в реализации конкретного мобильного браузера. Вы ведь, скорее всего, используете хоть и разные устройства, но на одной платформе и с одним и тем же браузерным движком? Убедитесь для начала, что событие вообще поддерживается.

Comment: в том ответе что я привел, говорится, что проблема именно в том, что в том же потоке вешается событие, где и задается audio, в вашем случае видимо надо делать setTimeout trick :)

Comment: Хм, проблема может быть в том, что аудиозапись  не успевает просто-напросто прогрузиться. Но а потоки-то тут причем?)

Comment: я не знаю, просто по описанию того ответа выходит, что надо отпустить поток, прежде чем ended вешать, в реализациях браузерных такое сплошь и рядом, вот вы например в курсе, что до 40й(или 38, я не помню точно) версии хрома после создания транзакции indexedDB нельзя писать console.log, ато она завершится неожиданно (и до сих пор нельзя ставить брейкпоинт в потоке транзакции).

Comment: На всех устройствах я все пробовал в Хроме. А добавление тега "preload="none" не решает проблему. то есть дело не в том, что не успевает загрузиться